# web service call from classic asp page does not return string but does not fail

Tags: web-services, soap, asp-classic

I am trying to call my .NET web service from a classic asp file.  I have to update the asp file to connect to a new web service.  This asp file is called by a 3rd party application and it pages a user.  I created a .NET console application to test this .asp file to simulate the 3rd party application's use of it. The console application runs locally.

When I run the console application, that runs the new version of the asp file that connects to my web service, there are no errors until I try to display the return result from the web service.  I suspect my SOAP request is incorrect.

The web service method is called 'TestMethod' and has no parameters.
This is the URL of the web service: 'http://:/Service1/Service1.Paging.svc'

This is my asp code:

```
Set httpRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")    
URL = "http://<servername><port>/Service1/Service1.Paging.svc/"  
httpRequest.Open "POST", URL, False 
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8" 
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", URL & "TestMethod"

Dim strSoapReq
strSoapReq = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>"
strSoapReq = strSoapReq & "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">"
strSoapReq = strSoapReq & "<s:Body>"
strSoapReq = strSoapReq & "<TestMethod xmlns=""http://<servername><port>/Service1"">"
strSoapReq = strSoapReq & "</TestMethod>"
strSoapReq = strSoapReq & "</s:Body>"
strSoapReq = strSoapReq & "</s:Envelope>"

Response.Write(strSoapReq)
httpRequest.Send(strSoapReq) 

Dim strResult
strResult = httpRequest.responseText
If IsNull(strResult) Then
    strResult = "No result"
End If
Response.Write("Result from web service: " & strResult);
```

If I comment out the `Response.Write` there is no error. The console application completes.  If I attempt to write the result, I get a 500 error.

I cannot debug the asp.  It is on a production server and there are no Visual Studio IDEs on the server.

Is my SOAP request correct? (strSoapReq)
I am not sure that I am defining the namespace correctly.  Should it just be the path with the namespace at the end?

If anyone has any ideas on how to debug this file, I would appreciate it.

Lastly, all the `TestMethod()` does is return a string, "Connected to TestMethod"

**UPDATE**
I can  connect to my web service.  When I run my console application, it returns the standard message of a web service when you but the URL in the web browser.  Basically..."
[image]

The TestMethod() is not called in the .asp file
When requesting the SOAPAction, is this line correct?
`URL = "http://<serverName>:<port>/Service1/Service1.Paging.svc"`
`httpRequest.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", URL & "/TestMethod"`

Secondly, I suspect my SOAP request string might not be correct.
In defining the namespace, I am doing the following:
'":/Service1"">"'

Comment: Have you enabled detailed error messages in IIS?  Have you tried debugging in Visual Studio?

Comment: `Response.Write("Result from web service: " & strResult);` You don't need the semicolon at the end. It happens when you code in multiple languages :)

Comment: Yep.  I usually write in C#.  So removing the semicolon allowed the console program to not error.  However, there is no value in the `strResult` string.  I would love to debug this in Visual Studio.  How can I do that?  I have the page opened in Visual Studio locally.  I enabled error messages on the web site but where are they produced?  As you might have guessed, I have never written or debugged in this ancient language.

Comment: The remote debugger is not installed on the web server.  There is Microsoft CLR Debugger on the server.  Can I use that?

Comment: I am now at least connecting to my web service but it is not calling my TestMethod.  I updated my changes above.  I changed the 'POST' to a "GET" and I removed the final backslash on the URL definition.  What is returning is the page when you connect to a web service from the browser.  "You have created a service. To test this service..."  My SoapReq variable that is requesting the method must be incorrect.  I think it might have to be how I define the namespace.

Comment: The usual way to debug classic ASP is to add `Response.Write` statements in places where you want to know what's going on, possibly combined with `Response.End` (if the code is otherwise blowing up on you) and/or `On error resume next`. You do need to turn on detailed error messages in your browser & IIS, though, because otherwise you'll get a completely useless "this page could not be displayed" message.

Comment: Well, on the web server I turned on detail error messages but I am not getting any.  I am running a console application locally and connecting to the classic asp page on the server.  As I described above, my Response.Write for the result of the SOAPAction call to my web service returns the wsdl.  my httpRequest SOAPAction does not seem to be calling the specific method in the web service.  I think it has to do with how I am defining the web service namespace.  I am using 'http://<serverName>:<port>/FolderName/Service.Paging.  I don't think that is correct.  But I am investigating...

Comment: Looking in my wsdl, the TestMethod soapAction is defined this way: `soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IPaging/TestMethod"`  Is that how the SOAPAction should be defined in the httpRequest?